# OpenGL VAO and VBO properly organization

Tags: opengl

I need to render a model that has a structure similiar to this:

```
MESH_1
  TRANSFORMATION_1.1
  TRANSFORMATION_1.2
  TRANSFORMATION_1.n

MESH_2
  TRANSFORMATION_2.1
  TRANSFORMATION_2.2
  TRANSFORMATION_2.n

MESH_n
  TRANSFORMATION_n.1
  TRANSFORMATION_n.2
  TRANSFORMATION_n.n
```

I'm trying to render that using instancing. My doubt is how to properly organize the VAOs and VBOs for this.

The only way I could think of was to have one VAO for each mesh, which will contain one VBO for the vertices and another to the transformation matrices.

But since I have like 30k different meshes, then I'll have 30k draw calls. Am I doing this right?

I think that having a single VAO would be ideal, but since each mesh can have any number of instances, I have no idea if is it even possible to setup a single VAO for this scenario. Is that correct?

Comment: How many vertices are in a typical mesh?

Comment: If you have OpenGL 4.2+ you can store your meshes and matrices in a single VAO and render them with `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseInstance`. You won't get around 30k draw calls though, because GL needs to know how many faces each mesh has and how often it needs to be instanced.

Comment: @RetoKoradi Around 6 to 30 vertices